# Can the correct TIGER Line Id be returned for an address from the PostGIS Tiger Geocoder?

Tags: geocoding, postgis-2.0, tiger

After reviewing the PostGIS Tiger Geocoder documentation, I don't see a method of returning the TIGER Line Id for the address.  I would assume this is information is available internally as part of the the street range interpolation processing.

http://postgis.net/docs/Extras.html

Answer (score 2):

A geometry is returned as part of the geocode() result, by which you can use to locate the nearest ID from any table that has a geometry column.

```
select gid from tiger.edges order by st_setsrid(the_geom,4326) <-> ST_GeomFromText('POINT(-71.06941 42.34225)',4326) limit 1;
```